# VLOOKUP like 1 liner using awk

Tags: text-processing

Tons of threads regarding using awk as a VLOOKUP, and yet none seem to work when I try them out.

I have 2 files:

```
@BioPower3-IBM ~/Goldfish/Assemblies/HighLength/blastx $ head GAGA_all_merged_k125_VS_Danio.blastp_results
Sequence name   Hit desc.   E-Value Similarity
Locus_1_Transcript_1/1_Confidence_1.000_Length_2223 gnl|BL_ORD_ID|19336gi|50540432|ref|NP_001002682.1| calsequestrin-2 precursor [Danio rerio]  0.0 89
Locus_2_Transcript_11/19_Confidence_0.580_Length_7240   gnl|BL_ORD_ID|42660gi|688610863|ref|XP_009294955.1| PREDICTED: band 4.1-like protein 1 isoform X1 [Danio rerio] 0.0 97
Locus_4_Transcript_46/49_Confidence_0.453_Length_5901   gnl|BL_ORD_ID|39369gi|59858543|ref|NP_001012312.1| gelsolin [Danio rerio]   0.0 92
Locus_5_Transcript_115/115_Confidence_0.452_Length_8023 gnl|BL_ORD_ID|30731gi|528504026|ref|XP_001345885.4| PREDICTED: protein Jumonji [Danio rerio]    0.0 91
Locus_6_Transcript_18/27_Confidence_0.299_Length_3005   gnl|BL_ORD_ID|28851gi|688587725|ref|XP_009289915.1| PREDICTED: phosphatidylinositol binding clathrin assembly protein b isoform X6 [Danio rerio]    0.0 98
Locus_8_Transcript_198/200_Confidence_0.159_Length_4179 gnl|BL_ORD_ID|45364gi|52219062|ref|NP_001004604.1| BCSC-1 [Danio rerio] 0.0 86
Locus_9_Transcript_1/6_Confidence_0.600_Length_1266 gnl|BL_ORD_ID|10854gi|528479736|ref|XP_005165325.1| PREDICTED: cathepsin L1 isoform X1 [Danio rerio]    0.0 97
Locus_10_Transcript_2635/2635_Confidence_0.015_Length_11912 gnl|BL_ORD_ID|39467gi|116004513|ref|NP_001070618.1| 3-oxoacid CoA transferase 1b [Danio rerio]  0.0 97
Locus_11_Transcript_7/7_Confidence_0.647_Length_1989    gnl|BL_ORD_ID|6732gi|528475412|ref|XP_005164328.1| PREDICTED: cerebellar degeneration-related protein 2-like isoform X2 [Danio rerio]   0.0 96

@BioPower3-IBM ~/Goldfish/Assemblies/HighLength/blastx $ head GAGA_all_merged_k125.LocusList
Locus_1_Transcript_1/1_Confidence_1.000_Length_2223
Locus_2_Transcript_11/19_Confidence_0.580_Length_7240
Locus_3_Transcript_1/1_Confidence_1.000_Length_417
Locus_4_Transcript_46/49_Confidence_0.453_Length_5901
Locus_5_Transcript_115/115_Confidence_0.452_Length_8023
Locus_6_Transcript_18/27_Confidence_0.299_Length_3005
Locus_7_Transcript_2/7_Confidence_0.611_Length_2222
Locus_8_Transcript_198/200_Confidence_0.159_Length_4179
Locus_9_Transcript_1/6_Confidence_0.600_Length_1266
Locus_10_Transcript_2635/2635_Confidence_0.015_Length_11912
```

Notice how the second file has all Loci counting from 1 onwards, while the first file skips a few, 3 and 7.

What I need an output of file 2 with columns (let's say column 2) from file 1 when the Locus is present in file #1. If Locus isn't present in File1, I want to see NA.

So far this is the closest I got, but it doesn't show the columns from file1:

```
@BioPower3-IBM ~/Goldfish/Assemblies/HighLength/blastx $ awk 'FNR == NR {keys[$1]; next} {if ($1 in keys) {print $1, $2} else {print $1, "NA"} }' GAGA_all_merged_k125_VS_Danio.blastp_results GAGA_all_merged_k125.LocusList | head
Locus_1_Transcript_1/1_Confidence_1.000_Length_2223 
Locus_2_Transcript_11/19_Confidence_0.580_Length_7240 
Locus_3_Transcript_1/1_Confidence_1.000_Length_417 NA
Locus_4_Transcript_46/49_Confidence_0.453_Length_5901 
Locus_5_Transcript_115/115_Confidence_0.452_Length_8023 
Locus_6_Transcript_18/27_Confidence_0.299_Length_3005 
Locus_7_Transcript_2/7_Confidence_0.611_Length_2222 NA
Locus_8_Transcript_198/200_Confidence_0.159_Length_4179 
Locus_9_Transcript_1/6_Confidence_0.600_Length_1266 
Locus_10_Transcript_2635/2635_Confidence_0.015_Length_11912
```

Notice 3 and 7 have the needed NA, however, how do I make others display what's in file1? Thanks, Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were near the end. What problems? You do:

```
FNR == NR {keys[$1]; next}
```

that saves nothing in the associative array. Replace with:

```
FNR == NR {keys[$1] = $1; next}
```

And when printing, `$2` does not exists:

```
if ($1 in keys) {print $1, $2}
```

Instead put the content saved in the associative array before:

```
if ($1 in keys) {print $1, keys[$1]}
```

So, it remains like:

```
awk '
    FNR == NR {keys[$1] = $1; next} 
    { if ($1 in keys) { print $1, keys[$1] } 
          else {print $1, "NA"} 
        }
' GAGA_all_merged_k125_VS_Danio.blastp_results GAGA_all_merged_k125.LocusList
```

---

**UPDATE based in comments**: It's similar to the previous one. Just remove first field and then save the whole line in the array.

```
awk '
    FNR == NR {f1 = $1; $1 = ""; keys[f1] = $0; next} 
    { if ($1 in keys) { print $1, keys[$1] } 
          else {print $1, "NA"} 
        }
' GAGA_all_merged_k125_VS_Danio.blastp_results GAGA_all_merged_k125.LocusList
```

It yields:

```
Locus_1_Transcript_1/1_Confidence_1.000_Length_2223  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|19336gi|50540432|ref|NP_001002682.1| calsequestrin-2 precursor [Danio rerio] 0.0 89
Locus_2_Transcript_11/19_Confidence_0.580_Length_7240  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|42660gi|688610863|ref|XP_009294955.1| PREDICTED: band 4.1-like protein 1 isoform X1 [Danio rerio] 0.0 97
Locus_3_Transcript_1/1_Confidence_1.000_Length_417 NA
Locus_4_Transcript_46/49_Confidence_0.453_Length_5901  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|39369gi|59858543|ref|NP_001012312.1| gelsolin [Danio rerio] 0.0 92
Locus_5_Transcript_115/115_Confidence_0.452_Length_8023  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|30731gi|528504026|ref|XP_001345885.4| PREDICTED: protein Jumonji [Danio rerio] 0.0 91
Locus_6_Transcript_18/27_Confidence_0.299_Length_3005  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|28851gi|688587725|ref|XP_009289915.1| PREDICTED: phosphatidylinositol binding clathrin assembly protein b isoform X6 [Danio rerio] 0.0 98
Locus_7_Transcript_2/7_Confidence_0.611_Length_2222 NA
Locus_8_Transcript_198/200_Confidence_0.159_Length_4179  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|45364gi|52219062|ref|NP_001004604.1| BCSC-1 [Danio rerio] 0.0 86
Locus_9_Transcript_1/6_Confidence_0.600_Length_1266  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|10854gi|528479736|ref|XP_005165325.1| PREDICTED: cathepsin L1 isoform X1 [Danio rerio] 0.0 97
Locus_10_Transcript_2635/2635_Confidence_0.015_Length_11912  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|39467gi|116004513|ref|NP_001070618.1| 3-oxoacid CoA transferase 1b [Danio rerio] 0.0 97
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for explaining this to me! any way to make the solution display column 2 for file1 when locus is present in file 1? What I mean is: the first line of the output should be: Locus_1_Transcript_1/1_Confidence_1.000_Length_2223 gnl|BL_ORD_ID|19336gi|50540432|ref|NP_001002682.1| calsequestrin-2 precursor [Danio rerio]

Comment: This is sooo cool! I really appreciate your help, Yeah I am still learning with awk, need to do more tutorials, thanks a lot!